# Menú desplegable multinivel

Tags: html, css

estoy usando el CSS que brinda el W3C, y quiero hacer un menú desplegable multi-nivel, pero no logro que lo haga. 
Copio el html para que vean cual es el problema.

```
<div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hide-small">
        <button class="w3-button" title="Administracion">Administración <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>     
        <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-card-4">
            <a href="" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">prueba</a>
            <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link</a>
            <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link</a>
            <div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-hide-small">
                <button class="w3-button" title="socios">socios <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></button>
                <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-card-4 w3-bar-block">
                    <a href="" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">link 1</a>
                    <a href="" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">link 2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda relacionarel la hoja css a tu proyecto, aunque te sugeriria que crees las clases css, en base a los ejemplos de *W3Schools" y lo referencies desde el assets correspondiente de tu proyecto, así te evitas links de terceros.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
```

Comment: Hola Anjelo, sí lo tengo referenciado en mi proyecto, pero no encuentro en ningún lado del w3c un ejemplo de Dropdown  multinivel.

Comment: Hay muchos, revisa la respuesta de este hilo... [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467377/bootstrap-4-multilevel-dropdown-inside-navigation)
la respuesta de Gerhard Götz es lo que buscas :)